# General topology terminology questions

Tags: gn.general-topology

In a Hausdorff but not regular space, collapsing certain closed sets to a point may produce a non-Hausdorff space.  Does there exist a term for closed sets one may collapse and still have a Hausdorff space?

Similar question for spaces regular but not normal.

Lacking a better term, let me call such closed sets "nice-1" and "nice-2."

Then one can weaken the notion of compactness by asking merely that finite intersection property families of nice-i closed sets have non-empty intersection (for i=1 or 2).
Do either of these weakenings of compactness occur in the literature and/or have a name?

Answer (score 3):

In Geometric Invariant Theory, the study of quotients in algebraic geometry, some points are ignored in the quotient (by its construction) that would make the quotient non-Hausdorff. These points are called 'unstable'. Sometimes the set of all unstable points is called the 'unstable locus'. This is of course just a special case of your question, in a slightly different area, but perhaps the terminology is used elsewhere. A good reference for this if you're interested is [these notes](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512411) by Richard Thomas.